# Error installing PostgreSQL Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rubygems

I have used RVM to install ruby and rails, and now am trying to install PostgreSQL via

```
Sudo Gem install pg
```

All my other gems seem to be installing fine. This may be due to the fact that I uninstalled and reinstalled RVM

However I get the following error

```
    Mikes-MacBook-Air:innoblue Silvis$ sudo gem install pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/include -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o compat.o -c compat.c
gcc -I. -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/Users/Silvis/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/include -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o pg.o -c pg.c
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_exec’:
pg.c:947: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:986: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_prepare’:
pg.c:1052: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_exec_prepared’:
pg.c:1143: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1173: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_s_escape’:
pg.c:1317: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1324: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_query’:
pg.c:1497: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1536: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_prepare’:
pg.c:1601: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_query_prepared’:
pg.c:1690: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1721: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_wait_for_notify’:
pg.c:2096: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_put_copy_data’:
pg.c:2166: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_block’:
pg.c:2579: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:2585: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
pg.c:2600: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_locreate’:
pg.c:2863: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘find_or_create_johab’:
pg.c:3933: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c:3939: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_get_client_encoding_as_rb_encoding’:
pg.c:3967: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_get_rb_encoding_as_pg_encname’:
pg.c:3999: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_internal_encoding_set’:
pg.c:4058: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_external_encoding’:
pg.c:4114: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
gcc -dynamic -bundle -o pg_ext.bundle compat.o pg.o -L. -L/Users/Silvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -L/Users/Silvis/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: file not found: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Silvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Silvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.12.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I tried that. I just got it working. I had to do brew uninstall postgresql and then brew install postgresql

Comment: Note for those on OS X 10.7: postgres is now installed by default. type psql on the cli. You still need the gem, of course.

Comment: @MikeSilvis, could you put the solution you put in the comments in an answer so I can upvote it?  That would remove this from the list of unanswered questions and you'd get a little reputation boost too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that. I just got it working. I had to do brew uninstall postgresql and then brew install postgresql